# Ingress to redirect to external resource using ALB

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-cloudfront, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have some services running on the cluster, and the ALB is working fine. But I have a CloudFront distribution, and I want to use the cluster as an entry point because of some internal factors. So, I am trying to add an ingress to redirect the requests to the CloudFront distribution based on the default rule or a named host, both will work.

I tried 2 different ways, but no dice:

Creating an external name and the ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: default
annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: "internet-facing"
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":80,"HTTPS": 443}]'
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: <my-cert-arn>
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { 
  "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: <my-group-name>
spec:
  rules:
    - host: test.my-host.net
      HTTP:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: test
              servicePort: use-annotation
            path: /
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: test.my-host.net
```

I also tried to create the ingress with the redirect with the annotation on the ALB Ingress v2 just like the docs:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: "internet-facing"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":80,"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: <my-cert-arn>
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { 
"Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.redirect-to-eks: >
      {"type":"redirect","redirectConfig":{"host":"my- 
 dist.cloudfront.net","path":"/","port":"443",
"protocol":"HTTPS","query":"k=v","statusCode":"HTTP_302"}}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: <my-group-name>
spec:
  rules:
    - host: <my-host-name>
      HTTP:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: ssl-redirect
              servicePort: use-annotation
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why it isn't working with `ExternalName` service type is because it has no endpoints. ALB can set target only to `instance` or `ip` ([documentation](https://github.com/HotelsDotCom/alb-ingress-controller/blob/master/docs/ingress-resources.md)) so `ExternalName` isn't an option here.

You can create redirect with annotation but it is a bit tricky. **First**, you need at least two subnets with public access for `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets` annotation. Subnets can be automatically discovered but I don't know if it can pick public ones from all assigned to EKS cluster, so it's better to set explicitly. **Second**, you need to use `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.<ACTION NAME>` annotation ([documentation](https://github.com/HotelsDotCom/alb-ingress-controller/blob/master/docs/ingress-resources.md)), where `<ACTION NAME>` must match `serviceName` from ingress rules. **Third**, you need to specify `Host` in redirect config or it'll be `host` from ingress `spec`.

Here is a working example:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-alb
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: "internet-facing"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: "public-subnet-id1,public-subnet-id2"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":80,"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Host":"example.com", "port":"443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: alb-test.host.name
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: redirect
              servicePort: use-annotation
```

Your `ssl-redirect` annotation is almost correct, except that it redirects to `<my-host-name>`. I recommend you to use the web console (change region in the link) https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=eu-central-1#LoadBalancers:sort=loadBalancerName to see generated redirect rules and debug other options.

There are other options to solve this, a dedicated deployment with `nginx` for example. Or you can use [nginx ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/), from my experience it is much easier to set redirect with it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out.

Unfortunately, we need to use ALB because AWS WAF is a requirement.

Comment: thanks, @anemyte, that worked

Unfortunately, I just found that ALB doesn´t have support for rewrite just yet. So I will probably need to throw a nginx pod into the mix

Comment: Glad to help. I'd definitely used nginx.